# Cannot connect to an EC2 instance through web sockets

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, akka-http

I am running an Akka HTTP service on port 8080 in my EC2 instance. It expects web socket connections, but normal HTTP should return 400 bad request.

I use this code to start Akka service:

`Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)`

From the remote terminal I have this expected behavior, but not from outside.

```
$ wget ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
--2017-10-01 15:27:31--  http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/
Resolving ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com... XX.XXX.XX.XXX
Connecting to ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com|XX.XXX.XX.XXX|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

Here is my inbound rules configuration:

[image: Security group]

If I do `netstat --listen -p` the port 8080 does not appear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. I should be binding the service to the private IP address of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Where? Under security groups in the source field? Or do you mean the IP address you connect to?

Comment: When creating the Akka binding, Http().bindAndHandle(route, "private EC2 IP address", 8080)